# Powered USB hub not charging phone. Kernel options?

Tags: usb, charging, kernel

I got a powered USB 2.0 hub (ET-UP900). As power source I am using the phones charger. But if I connect the hub with my phone (SM-C115) it does not charge. If I connect the charger directly it works.

My first thought was the hub does not provide enough power. But if I do the same thing with a tablet (SM-P905), which requires more power, it does work.

Also strange: If the hub is powered it does not work. If the hub is not powered it works just fine.

As I am using a custom build kernel I am looking a dmesg and fiddling with kernel options and driver to find the correct setting.

Maybe someone can give me a hint what might work?

Alternative: Any cable I can plugin in between to charge the phone and use the USB hub? I got a OTG charging cable but it would power the USB hub instead of the phone.

**UPDATE**
I found something about a [special cable with a resistor](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/general/hw-mod-usb-otg-charging-galaxy-s3-t1953061) to get into a special AUDIODOCK mode. I did found this AUDIODOCK in the source code of a related driver I saw in dmesg `drivers/misc/max77803-muic.c`. Maybe I can change the driver to force this mode all the time or something like this...

**UPDATE 2**
In `drivers/misc/max77803-muic.c` I saw the CONFIG_MUIC_MAX77803_SUPPORT_OTG_AUDIO_DOCK option needs to be set and the driver I got here does not support this anyway. I guess I try to use a [updated driver](https://github.com/danielpanzella/P900-kernel-source/blob/master/drivers/mfd/max77803.c). With AUDIO_DOCK support implemented.

Comment: `Also strange: If the hub is powered it does not work. If the hub is not powered it works just fine.` what do you mean by "powered" here?

Comment: @LieRyan The USB hub has a power plug. It is optional to plugin power here. This USB device type is named LANHUB in the [driver](https://github.com/danielpanzella/P900-kernel-source/blob/master/drivers/misc/max77803-muic.c#L104) it has a 80.07K ohm resistor on the signal pin. If I am able to get this updated driver working the problem would be solved I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it running. The [max77803](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/reliability/product/MAX77803_prelim.pdf) chip in the SM-C115 was also used in the S4 but the driver my kernel had did not support the ET-UP900 device. So I searched for newer kernel driver and found [danielpanzella/P900-kernel-source](https://github.com/danielpanzella/P900-kernel-source/). In this driver they call the device [LANHUB](https://github.com/danielpanzella/P900-kernel-source/blob/be75c49eba1d4d1b6c9e3d3362fbfc67ed29fbfe/drivers/misc/max77888-muic.c#L101). If you have a look at the code there are a number of other devices, too. The driver detects depending on resistor on the signal pin what type of devices is connected.

I searched the repository for [LANHUB](https://github.com/danielpanzella/P900-kernel-source/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=LANHUB) and merged those code lines into my kernel, build the kernel, installed it with odin and it worked!

The USB hub, it's network card and attached USB devices are working while I get power from the hub charging the phone.

**Update**

Some steps to reproduce this. I used Vagrant as enviroment to get a clean linux box running. Download [NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) and the source code of the kernel and setup a cross compiler see [any Kernel Tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2152819):

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential kernel-package libncurses5-dev bzip2
export CROSS_COMPILE=/home/vagrant/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
export ARCH=arm
```

Next you need to pick the right config file for your device:

```
cp arch/arm/configs/whatever .config
```

Edit the config to add a driver:

```
make menuconfig
```

For the ET-UP900 adapter goto in "Device Drivers" > "Network Device Support" > "USB Network Adapters". Select "Multi-purpose USB Networking Framework" and "SMSC LAN95XX base USB 2.0 10/100 ethernet devices"

If charing is not working look at "Device Driver" > "Misc". Enable settings with "SUPPORT_LANHUB" in it.

Now save and exit menuconfig and build the kernel:

```
make bzImage
```

Your new kernel will be `arch/arm/boot/zImage`. Now you need to pack this togther with a ramdisk (Android kernel kitchen) into a boot.img and flash it to the device (Odin).

With the new kernel and the adapter attached bash command `netcfg` should show you eth0. Run `dhcpcd -k eth0` to get an IP.

To see if something is not working have a look at `dmesg`.

Comment: Hello do you think the same can be done for Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10" P5200. I would really love if this adapter could provide me with LAN and USB ports.

Comment: How do I go about adding these to my kernel?

Comment: Looks like it. I download the [source code](http://opensource.samsung.com/reception/receptionSub.do?method=sub&sub=F&searchValue=P5200), unpacked the kernel, and there is a `drivers\net\usb\smsc95xx.c` driver. I update my answer with some details...

Comment: @JoelDean Ok, I posted some steps that might help you. Basically you only need to compile a new kernel and enable the driver. In my case the got it working but it did not charge. For charging I needed to patch the charging driver with a newer version. That would be difficult...

Comment: Okay. I dont know how to modify kernels. Would you be able to do it for me if I paid you. I really need this adapter to work with my tablet. You could give me an email and we talk through there.

Comment: @JoelDean At the moment I don't have the time to do it for you. Try to [build the kernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/ultimate-guide-compile-android-kernel-t2871276) and enable the driver in the menuconfig. Maybe you don't need to change anything else.